# how to open pdf into pdf viewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a pdf book i want to open this pdf in pdf viewer on the browser in asp.net like 
"http://wdn.ipublishcentral.net/informatics/viewinside/40590590200230"
Would you suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

`<iframe>` tag is used for this.

Try using this tag as like following:

```
 <iframe src="anyfilename.PDF" width="810px" height="700px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

If you are using telerik controls as like the link you provided then use following>>

```
<radPdf:PdfWebControl id="PdfWebControl1" runat="server" height="600px" width="100%" />
```

and codebehind>>

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            //Get PDF as byte array from file (or database, browser upload, remote storage, etc)
            byte[] pdfData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\demo.pdf");

            //Load PDF byte array into RAD PDF
            this.PdfWebControl1.CreateDocument("Document Name", pdfData);
        }
```

Hope its helpful!!!

Comment: it is usefull no doubt. but i would like to the below given link  "http://wdn.ipublishcentral.net/informatics/viewinside/40590590200230"

Comment: would you please check the  "http://www.nxtbook.com/nxtbooks/nxtbook_samples/ft_201110/#/6"

Comment: and click on "PREVIEW" BUTTON

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re this article might help you.